# shortnames and parallel file copy

Tags: winapi, filesystems, ntdll

I am dealing with code that:

- enumerates source and destination directories and generates {`src`, `dst`} pairs
- ... each pair is sent to a pool of worker threads
- ... which performs the work, for example "copy `src` to `dst`"

(all this is simplified quite a bit).

**Problem:**

When file gets created it also gets a shortname which can be the same as another file in source directory (name collision) which leads to variety of effects (depending on the order of operations). For example, copying two files `my file` and `MYFILE~1` can produce 2 or 1 files in destination (depending on your luck), probably with corrupted content (in latter case).

**Question:**

How to avoid problems that arise from such collisions? Would be nice to have a function that creates/opens a file ignoring shortnames...

**Notes:**

- can't assume anything about the way shortname is generated. Various systems employ different schemes (see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040414-00/?p=39813/))
- even if you run these jobs in sequential manner (one-by-one) -- they need to be executed in order which depends on shortname generation logic (which is unknown). Plus this implies loading and sorting/etc entire directory in memory before running any jobs
- both source and destination can be very big (potentially millions files), (if possible) I'd like to avoid loading entire directory into memory or enumerating it multiple times
- can't switch off shortname generation in destination volume and making it a requirement is not an option (plus, switching it off doesn't remove existing shortnames anyway)
- application is limited only to Win32 API and NT API

**Edit:** it occurred to me that in general case you can't do it even if everything happens on one thread -- simply because regardless of order you choose, there will be a shortname generation scheme and a set of filenames that is guaranteed to produce a collision during processing.

If this is correct -- how system utilities copy files? Do they assume something about shortnames or perform "validate and fix discrepancies" after copy is complete?

Comment: Are you sure you've diagnosed this correctly? I really doubt the filesystem will create two files with the same short name.

Comment: No, it won't. Copying `my file` (which has `MYFILE~2` shortname) will create `my file` in dst directory (likely with `MYFILE~1` shortname). If after this you copy `MYFILE~1` (which doesn't have shortname) -- it will overwrite file created on previous step and (depending on many things) probably corrupt it's data (if copy happens in parallel).

Comment: Why are you using short filenames at all?  Copy the files using their full filenames.  On some filesystems, you can even turn off the generation of short filenames.

Comment: @Remy I think the asker is copying using the full filenames, but the short filename generated on the destination is different from that at the source, and then interferes with subsequent operations.

Comment: @C.M. I'd wonder why you are using threads for an operation which is not CPU bound

Comment: @DavidHeffernan First of all -- you don't know that... Second, it isn't my code, tbh. Third, I'd be happy to move everything into one thread that uses async i/o and spins an event loop yada-yada, but unfortunately, this is a lot of work (rewriting the code), Win32 API lacks certain functionality (createfile always blocks, for example) and ultimately it won't help me with this problem, because (as mentioned in the question) problem can happen even if everything is processed sequentially on one thread.

Comment: Disk copying is never cpu bound. If the problem exists for single threaded code then it's going to be easiest to deal with it in that context first. What api are you using to copy the files?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "copy" was just an example of "work" that might be performed for given `{src,dst}` pair. Data may be translated, encoded, etc. Problem is that I can't guarantee that `N` source files will transform into `N` distinct files on destination. Thank you, Bill Gates, for that awesome idea with auto-generated shortnames...

Comment: Never mind. If we can't home in on a problem it's hard to say any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem basically boils down to following: `dst` should never be opened via `shortname`.

For example (in case of `NT API`) this can be achieved like this:

- when opening (`NtCreateFile()`, no truncate) `dst` use `FILE_OPEN_IF` as `CreateDisposition`
- on success check `IoStatusBlock::Information` if file was created (`FILE_CREATED`)

  - if yes -- nothing needs to be done (it is impossible to create a file via shortname)
  - if no -- check current file name via `NtQueryInformationFile(FileNameInformation)`

    - if name differs (case-sensitivity!) from name supplied to `NtCreateFile()` -- error

It is possible for parallel process to rename file right after you opened it, but I'd treat it as an error.

Error can lead to couple of retries followed by hard failure (that needs human attention). Shouldn't be too hard to fix the issue manually (or even programmatically) since name of conflicting file is returned by `NtQueryInformationFile()`.

P.S. Additional steps can be taken to prevent/reduce collisions. For example, if shortname generation logic is known -- `dst` objects can be processed in certain order.